# File parameter substitution: Movie creation with png files

Tags: windows-xp, ffmpeg

I've a simple question: I try to create a movie file like mentioned above (have a lot of png-files with name plt_.png). When I try to run the commandline input:

ffmpeg -q:v 5 -r 2 -b:v 9600 -i plt_%d.png movie.mp4

... I receive the error message: "plt_d.png: No such file or directory".

This is because XP tries to substitute % by command line paramenter 0, I think. But this substitution shouldn't be done here but one stage deeper by ffmpeg.

Do you have an idea to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the argument, i.e. ffmpeg -q:v 5 -r 2 -b:v 9600 -i "plt_%d.png" movie.mp4?

Comment: @satuon: thats it! I tried to do this before but misleadingly putting the jpg extension to the end. Your answer gave me afresh push to take a look on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put quotes around the argument.

So

```
ffmpeg -q:v 5 -r 2 -b:v 9600 -i plt_%d.png movie.mp4
```

becomes

```
ffmpeg -q:v 5 -r 2 -b:v 9600 -i "plt_%d.png" movie.mp4?
```